# How to read partially corrupt hdf5 files with highfive in c++?

Tags: c++, hdf5

I'm using the header-only C++ HDF5 interface "highfive/H5Easy" to load my h5 files:

```
auto file = H5Easy::File{path, H5Easy::File::ReadOnly};
auto p1= H5Easy::load<std::vector<float>>(file, "/ABC/"+ p + "/p1");
```

The problem is that some of my files are partially corrupted which produces the following error.

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.12.2) thread 1:
  #000: H5D.c line 285 in H5Dopen2(): unable to open dataset
    major: Dataset
    minor: Can't open object
  #001: H5VLcallback.c line 1910 in H5VL_dataset_open(): dataset open failed
    major: Virtual Object Layer
    minor: Can't open object
  #002: H5VLcallback.c line 1877 in H5VL__dataset_open(): dataset open failed
    major: Virtual Object Layer
    minor: Can't open object
  #003: H5VLnative_dataset.c line 123 in H5VL__native_dataset_open(): unable to open dataset
    major: Dataset
    minor: Can't open object
  #004: H5Dint.c line 1477 in H5D__open_name(): not a dataset
    major: Dataset
    minor: Inappropriate type
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'HighFive::DataSetException'
  what():  Unable to open the dataset "/ABC": (Dataset) Inappropriate type
```

**Is there any way to read chunks of the file that are still ok and just skip the corrupted ones?**

Comment: Read the raw bytes??